# Is there a way to configure max file count in embedded Tomcat for a Spring Boot project?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, file-upload

We have microservices using Spring Boot and Java. We are using the embedded Tomcat web server that comes with Spring Boot. I know that we can set max file size and max request size using the parameters below:

spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB

spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB

However; a recent CVE (https://security.snyk.io/vuln/SNYK-JAVA-ORGAPACHETOMCATEMBED-3326459) opened against Tomcat requires that we set a new parameter for max file count. Is there a way to set this parameter for the embedded tomcat either through an application property file or custom coding?

I have tried using the spring.servlet.multipart properties, but there is no current file limit parameter that I can see. I also looked at the MultipartConfigElement that gets added as part of the latest version 9 of tomcat embedded core (org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:9.0.75 and I still only see maxFileSize, maxRequestSize, and fileSizeThreshold.

I was thinking I might be able to do something like the below, but that class doesn't have the MaxFileCount parameter to set:

```
@Bean
public MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
    MultipartConfigFactory factory = new MultipartConfigFactory();
    factory.setMaxFileSize("124MB");
    factory.setMaxRequestSize("124MB");
    factory.setMaxFileCount(10); // Set the maximum number of files here
    return factory.createMultipartConfig();
```

Comment: Not an answer, just an observation: the class you want is `org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUpload` which is found in `tomcat-coyote.jar` (it's repackaged from Commons FileUpload). So, you can prove to yourself that you can access this from Spring: `new FileUpload().setFileCountMax(20)` - but that's not going to help you, I think (it just shows that the updated class is available). This does not appear to have been made visible to Spring (yet). As you note there is not (yet) a `spring.servlet.multipart` property for `fileCountMax`.

Comment: Maybe someone knows how to hack embedded Tomcat in Spring for this...